# Capture Event 'raycaster-intersected' AFRAME

Tags: javascript, events, three.js, aframe

I need to capture the event `raycaster-intersected` every time it occurs.

I need the distance to the first entity detected to check collisions, but the event only fires the first time raycaster hits a entity.

If raycaster still touches the entity, it doesn't fire the event.

I have the next code:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent("follow-body", {
  'schema': {
    entityId: {
      type:'string',
      default:''
    }
  },
  init: function(){
    this.pibot = document.querySelector("#" + this.data.entityId);
  },
  tick: function(){
    let pibotPos = this.pibot.object3D.position;
    let pibotRotation = this.pibot.object3D.rotation;
    let el = this.el;
    pibotPos.y += 0.2;

    el.object3D.position.set(pibotPos.x, pibotPos.y, pibotPos.z);
    el.object3D.rotation.set(pibotRotation.x, pibotRotation.y, pibotRotation.z);
    el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersection', function(evt){
      var e = new CustomEvent('intersection-detected', {detail: evt.detail});
      this.dispatchEvent(e);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The code snippet doesn't run.

    Error: {
      "message": "Script error.",
      "filename": "",
      "lineno": 0,
      "colno": 0
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a custom component like this:
- `raycaster-intersected` event fires - you store the raycaster 
- `raycaster-intersected-cleared` - you nullify the the raycaster reference 
- on `tick`, if the raycaster reference exists, get the intersection point, and do your calculations.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected", evt => {
      this.intersectingRaycaster = evt.detail.el.components.raycaster;
    });
    this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected-cleared", () => {
      this.intersectingRaycaster = null;
    });
  },
  tick: function() {
     if (!this.intersectingRaycaster) {
        return;
     }

     const intersection = this.intersectingRaycaster.getIntersection(this.el);
     if (intersection) {
        let point = intersection.point;
        // your calculations
     }
  }
});
```

Check it out in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/sa4d8237/12/).

Comment: I posted this yesterday, what i see on source code from AFRAME is 'raycaster-intersection' only fires on new intersection so i need to calculate position manually.

Comment: yup, thats why you need to detect when the intersection occured, and when it stopped. Btw the position of the intersection is in the **point** reference in my code. Is my example not working ?

Comment: Yes, it seems similar to what i coded, i register a variable boolean true when raycaster-intersection fires and i store the position of the object where raycaster is pointing. Next i calculate the distance between raycaster and the object. And cleared all when raycaster-intersection-cleared.